# Reducer is not being called in hadoop mapreduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have two mapper classes which simply create key-value pairs my main logic is supposed to be in the reducer part.I am trying to compare data from two different text files.
My mapper class is

```
public static class Map extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private String ky,vl="a";

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String line = value.toString();
            String tokens[] = line.split("\t");
            vl = tokens[1].trim();
            ky = tokens[2].trim();
    //sending key-value pairs to the reducer
            context.write(new Text(ky),new Text(vl));
    }
}
```

My second mapper is

```
public static class Map2 extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private String ky2,vl2 = "a";
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         String line = value.toString();
            String tokens[] = line.split("\t");
            vl2 = tokens[1].trim();
            ky2 = tokens[2].trim();
    //sending key-value pairs to the reducer
            context.write(new Text(ky2),new Text(vl2));

    }
}
```

Reducer class is

```
public static class Reduce extends
        Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

  private String rslt = "l";

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          int count = 0;
            while(values.hasNext()){
            count++;
            }
            rslt = Integer.toString(count);
       if(count>1){    
            context.write(key,new Text(rslt));
          }
    }

}
```

And my main method is

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(CompareTwoFiles.class);
    job.setJobName("Compare Two Files and Identify the Difference");
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]),
            TextInputFormat.class, Map.class);
    MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]),
            TextInputFormat.class, Map2.class);
    job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

output

```
    File System Counters
    FILE: Number of bytes read=361621  
 FILE: Number of bytes written=1501806
    FILE: Number of read operations=0
    FILE: Number of large read operations=0
    FILE: Number of write operations=0
    HDFS: Number of bytes read=552085
    HDFS: Number of bytes written=150962
    HDFS: Number of read operations=28
    HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
    HDFS: Number of write operations=5
Map-Reduce Framework
    Map input records=10783
    Map output records=10783
    Map output bytes=150962
    Map output materialized bytes=172540
    Input split bytes=507
    Combine input records=0
    Combine output records=0
    Reduce input groups=7985
    Reduce shuffle bytes=172540
    Reduce input records=10783
    Reduce output records=10783
    Spilled Records=21566
    Shuffled Maps =2
    Failed Shuffles=0
    Merged Map outputs=2
    GC time elapsed (ms)=12
    Total committed heap usage (bytes)=928514048
Shuffle Errors
    BAD_ID=0
    CONNECTION=0
    IO_ERROR=0
    WRONG_LENGTH=0
    WRONG_MAP=0
    WRONG_REDUCE=0
File Input Format Counters 
    Bytes Read=0
File Output Format Counters 
    Bytes Written=150962
```

Comment: Why do you need this two mapper classes? It seems like both do the same. Could you please describe a little bit more detailed what is going wrong? Is the reducer not started? What is the exit state of the job?

Comment: I am using two files because i am taking user input and storing in the other file. The output is same as the result after mapping...the result gets sorted though(i am guessing its implementing default reducer).

Comment: What I meant is that Map and Map2 does the same so Map can be reused. But could you please describe what happens to the reducer? Can you see it at the job-tracker?

Comment: here , i have posted the output as well. Everything works without any halt, but my reducer code is not executed.

Comment: So your reducer does some work but the output is not as you expected right? Could you please post a sample of your input? Maybe it's a good idea to remove the if clause (count > 1)  in your reducer to find this output too.

Comment: @0309gunner It is being executed. It clearly shows  Reduce input records=10783
    Reduce output records=10783